# How can I display more than one table in models in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to submit a form and this form needs to submit in two different separate tables in the database in Laravel.

I have a `plan_notifications` table and second one is pricing plan table. How can I submit form containing values of both these tables? Any help would be appreciated?

**AddPlanModel**

```
class AddPlanModel extends Model { 

    protected $table = 'pricing_plan';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'price',
        'allowed_users',
        'can_trail',
        'trail_duration',
        'detail1',
        'detail2'‌​,
        'staff_profiles',
        'space_management',
        'currency_unit',
        'is_active',
        'is_deleted'
    ];

    public $timestamps = true; 
}
```

**NotificationModel**

```
class NotificationModel extends Model {

    protected $table = 'plan_notifications';

    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'company_name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'phone_number'
    ];

    protected $hidden = ['password'];

}
```

**View**

```
@extends('sadmin.main-template')
@section('title', 'Super admin Dashboard')

@section('title', 'Add Plan')


@section('content')
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 right-sidebar admin-client add-client">
        @include('partials.errors')
        <form action="{{url('add/plan')}}" class="toggle-disabled" method="post">
            {!! csrf_field() !!}
        <h3 class="title">Add a plan</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label >You Can Create Your Plan Here</label>
        </div>
                <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 left-client-title">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label name">
                    <span class="form-name">First Name</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="first_name"  placeholder="" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([A-Za-z ]+)$">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label name">
                    <span class="form-name">Last Name</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="last_name"  placeholder="" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([A-Za-z ]+)$">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label name">
                    <span class="form-name">Company Name</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="company_name"  placeholder="" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([A-Za-z ]+)$">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label name">
                    <span class="form-name">Email</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="email"  placeholder="" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([A-Za-z ]+)$">
                </label>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label name">
                <span class="form-name">Password</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="password"  placeholder="" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([A-Za-z ]+)$">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label name">
                <span class="form-name">Phone Number</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" name="phone_number" placeholder="" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([A-Za-z ]+)$">
            </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 right-client-add">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label name">
                <span class="form-name">Allowed Users</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="allowedUsers" name="allowed_users" placeholder=""data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([A-Za-z ]+)$" >
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label name">
                <span class="form-name">Can Trail</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CanTrail" name="can_trail" placeholder="" data-validation="" >
            </label>
        </div>
            </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 left-client-title">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label name">
                <span class="form-name">Trail Duration</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="trailDuration" name="trail_duration" placeholder="" data-validation="">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label name">
                <span class="form-name">Detail</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="detail" name="detail1" placeholder="" data-validation="">
            </label>
        </div>
            </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 right-client-add">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label name">
                <span class="form-name">Plan Detail</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="detail" name="detail2" placeholder="" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([0-9 +-]+)$">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label name">
                <span class="form-name">Staff Profile</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="staffProfile" name="staff_profiles" placeholder="" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([0-9 +-]+)$">
            </label>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 left-client-title">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label name">
                <span class="form-name">Space Management</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="spaceManagement" name="space_management" placeholder="" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([0-9 +-]+)$">
            </label>
        </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 left-client-title">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label name">
                <span class="form-name">Currency Unit</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="currencyUnit" name="currency_unit" placeholder="" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([0-9 +-]+)$">
            </label>
        </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
            <div align="center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="padding-left:90px; padding-right:90px;"><strong>Send</strong></button>
            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>


    </div>

@endsection
```

Comment: Please provide code!

Comment: This is my AddPlanModel with database table name   ' class AddPlanModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'pricing_plan';

    protected $fillable = ['name','price','allowed_users','can_trail','trail_duration','detail1','detail2','staff_profiles','space_management','currency_unit','is_active','is_deleted'];
    public $timestamps = true;
}'

Comment: and this is my Notification model with database name 'class NotificationModel extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'plan_notifications';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $fillable = ['first_name','last_name','company_name','email','password','phone_number'];

    protected $hidden = ['password'];
}'

Comment: @shahzadhussain Update your question with the code, don't add it as a comment. Thanks.

Comment: now i have view of form and i need to submit form in both tables given above .... how i can submit form values in both table ... any help plz

Comment: Add your view code as well, it may help!

Comment: The view is given above

Comment: Same form has  different values and need to submit values from one form into two different database tables

Answer (score 0):

Models are only meant to represent one table in a database. You should make a model for each table you wish to interact with.

See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#introduction):

> The Eloquent ORM included with Laravel provides a beautiful, simple ActiveRecord implementation for working with your database. **Each database table has a corresponding "Model" which is used to interact with that table**.

So, for the table `plan_notifications` make a model `PlanNotification` and for table `pricing_plans` make another named `PricingPlan`. The convention for naming of your tables is plural whereas your model should be singular. You can of course override this functionality.

There should be nothing stopping you from extracting data from your form submission and creating two separate interactions with the database to insert two different records in two separate tables.

If the two models are related you can take advantage of [Eloquent's relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships).

You'd do yourself a huge favour by getting through the [Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#introduction)

**Edit**

Before you do much more Laravel try and read the docs and complete the tutorials:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart-intermediate

There's also great videos here:

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch

As for your problem, well with some serious guess work here...

Assuming you have a route set up like so:

```
Route::post('add/plan', 'PlanController@add');
```

You could do this in your PlanController:

```
Use App\Notification;
Use App\Plan;

public function add(Request $request)
{
    Notification::create([
        'first_name' => $request->get('first_name'),
        'last_name' => $request->get('last_name'),
        'company_name' => $request->get('company_name'),
        'email' => $request->get('email'),
        'password' => $request->get('password'),
        'phone_number' => $request->get('phone_number'),
    ]);


    Plan::create([
        'allowed_users' => $request->get('allowed_users');,
        'can_trail' => $request->get('can_trail'),
        'trail_duration' => $request->get('trail_duration'),
        'detail1' => $request->get('detail1'),
        'detail2' => $request->get('detail2'),
        'staff_profiles' => $request->get('staff_profiles'),
        'space_management' => $request->get('space_management'),
        'currency_unit' => $request->get('currency_unit'),
        /*
            missing from request:
            name
            price
            is_active
            is_deleted
         */
    ]);

    return 'done';
}
```

Comment: but my form view is single and i need to submit my form in two different tables i know i can do it from eloquent relation but can u plz draw these relations here

Comment: @shahzadhussain 1. There's nothing stopping you from using two different models in your controller to insert two models! 2. Add your form view code to your question

Comment: There are no obvious relations between the models